# Clear All button doesn't uncheck all boxes in a ExpandableListView android?

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

I am using checkboxes in all child view elements in `ExpandableListView`. To clear all checkboxes in one go, I am using a button clearFilters and the code for the Adapter class and the button click event is below.

Clicking the button doesn't do anything at all. I want to clear all checkboxes when the button is clicked.Any help is greatly appreciated.

ExpandableListAdapterClass:

```
public class ExpandableListViewAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private List<String> expandableListTitle;
    private Map<String, List<ChildViewModel>> expandableListDetail;
    private static List<ChildViewHolder> checkedViewHolders=new ArrayList<>();
    static int checkedBoxesCount;

    public ExpandableListViewAdapter(Context context, List<String> expandableListTitle, Map<String,
            List<ChildViewModel>> expandableListDetail) {
        this.context = context;
        this.expandableListTitle = expandableListTitle;
        this.expandableListDetail = expandableListDetail;
    }
    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return expandableListTitle.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return expandableListDetail.get(expandableListTitle.get(groupPosition)).size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return expandableListTitle.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public ChildViewModel getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return expandableListDetail.get(expandableListTitle.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        String listTitle=getGroup(groupPosition);
        GroupViewHolder groupViewHolder;
        if(view==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.expanded_list_group,null);
            groupViewHolder=new GroupViewHolder();
            groupViewHolder.listTitleTextView=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtExpandedListTitle);
            view.setTag(groupViewHolder);
        }else {
            groupViewHolder=(GroupViewHolder)view.getTag();
        }
        groupViewHolder.listTitleTextView.setText(listTitle);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        final ChildViewModel expandedListText=getChild(groupPosition,childPosition);
        final ChildViewHolder childViewHolder;
        if(view==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.expanded_list_item,null);
            childViewHolder=new ChildViewHolder();
            childViewHolder.expandedListTextView=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtExpandedListItem);
            childViewHolder.checkBox=(CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.expandeditem_chkbox);
            view.setTag(childViewHolder);
        }else {
            childViewHolder=(ChildViewHolder)view.getTag();
        }
        childViewHolder.expandedListTextView.setText(expandedListText.getName());
        if(expandedListText.isCheckStatus()){
            childViewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(true);
        }else {
            childViewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(false);
        }

        childViewHolder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ChildViewModel model;
                if(childViewHolder.checkBox.isChecked()){
                    checkedBoxesCount++;
                    model=expandableListDetail.get(expandableListTitle.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
                    model.setCheckStatus(true);
                    expandableListDetail.get(expandableListTitle.get(groupPosition)).set(childPosition,model);
                    checkedViewHolders.add(childViewHolder);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                    Toast.makeText(context,"Checked value is"+expandableListDetail.get(expandableListTitle.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else {
                    checkedBoxesCount--;
                    if(checkedBoxesCount==0){
                        Toast.makeText(context,"nothing checked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(context,"unchecked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    model=expandableListDetail.get(expandableListTitle.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
                    model.setCheckStatus(false);
                    checkedViewHolders.remove(childViewHolder);
                    expandableListDetail.get(expandableListTitle.get(groupPosition)).set(childPosition,model);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    public void clearChecks(){
        for(int i=0;i<checkedViewHolders.size();i++){
            checkedViewHolders.get(i).checkBox.setChecked(false);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        checkedViewHolders.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

    public class GroupViewHolder {
        TextView listTitleTextView;
    }

    public class ChildViewHolder {
        TextView expandedListTextView;
        CheckBox checkBox;
    }
}
```

Here is the MainActivity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ExpandableListView mExpandableListView;

    ExpandableListViewAdapter mExpandableListAdapter;
    Button clearFilters;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mExpandableListView=(ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.expandedListView);
        clearFilters=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnClearFilter);


        mExpandableListAdapter=new ExpandableListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this,getTitles(),getNames());
        mExpandableListView.setAdapter(mExpandableListAdapter);

        clearFilters.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mExpandableListAdapter.clearChecks();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the motive is to simply uncheck all checkboxes, we can use this technique to iterate through the Hashmap and set all checked status to false. It will clear all checkboxes in all childViews.

```
public void clearChecks(){
        for (List<ChildViewModel> value:expandableListDetail.values()) {
            for(ChildViewModel sample:value){
                sample.setCheckStatus(false);
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
```